# populate a list in callback method of fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent

When use a class which extends the `ListActivity`, I can populate list in `onCreate()` method like below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
}
```

But I would like to use **Fragment** instead of **Activity**, I am wondering in which life-cycle callback method of fragment should I define the thing like above?  And can I directly copy the code above to use in the fragment callback?

**P.S.**
Fragment life-cycle callbacks are: `onAttach()`, `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, `onActivityCreated()`, `onStart()` and so on. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documents. Fragments are more or less like activities. You can still use the onCreate() method. Take a look at the resource [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Comment: Yes, I know that Fragment are like activity, but they are anyhow not the same, I have already read the document you provided, my question is in where I should define the thing in fragment. It is not clearly mentioned in the document.

Comment: Thank you. Besides, the ListFragment has already had the onListItemClick() callback, I guess I do not need the lv.setOnItemClickListener() in my fragment's onCreate(), right? Instead I should move this code to FragmentList 's onListItemClick() callback, right??

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ListFragment then you would do the same thing in onCreate() and in the simplest case you don't need to do anything in onCreateView() because that method returns the container with all of the rows of your list inside it.

Comment: You mean I can directly copy the code in onCreate() from activity and use it directly in my ListFragment, right? But the ListFragment has already had the onListItemClick() callback, I guess I do not need the lv.setOnItemClickListener() in my fragment's onCreate(), right?

Comment: Correct.  Right now you have an anonymous class that overrides the onItemClick() method of the OnItemClickListener class, you would strip that piece out and add that behavior to the onListItemClick method.  So basically just pull that code out and override onListItemClick() method to show your Toast object

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use your listview in `onResume()` method in case of fragmentation. Find out with this idea.This can help you more.I did something as this way.